# Are there any RPG systems that don't require a DM to narrate the adventure?

Tags: system-agnostic, game-recommendation

Are there any RPG systems that don't require a person narrating the adventure?

Comment: Video games perhaps? might be a duplicate to this question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141710/is-there-any-way-to-play-dd-without-a-dm

Comment: It might seem off-topic because https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic specifies that:Recommendations for RPGs to play - for those, use an RPG discussion forum. But it might seems like so, I disagree, the list after the ''YES'' in my answer makes this question look off-topic, but it was about rpg games like D&D. you might have better answers in one of those:  gaming.stackexchange.com/ boardgames.stackexchange.com /an RPG discussion forum (https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)

Comment: ''shopping questions'' are not accepted anymore as @V2Blast stated in another question. I was wrong it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YES**

I found a few games/system that might interest you:

- Fiasco
- The Quiet Year
- The Deep Forest
- Dream Askew
- Dream Apart
- Microscope
- Follow
- Kingdom
- Questlandia
- Noirlandia
- Mobile Frame Zero: Firebrands
- The King Is Dead
- Capes
- Polaris
- Ironsworn
- Mythic GM Emulator
- Amber diceless
- Field Work
- Children's Radio Hour
- White Books
- Goblin Quest
- Carolina Death Craw
- Durance
- Warhammer quest boardgame
- The Cue System (Cosmic Patrol, Valiant, Shadowrun Anarchy)

Comment: Thanks to a few pages on reddit, there might be more out there but I think that's a fair list to start!